# twig issue upon emarket theme activation

Tags: twig, opencart

I am facing this strange issue once i installed "emarket theme" and of course i cleared twig cache and refreshed modifications and activated all permissions from user groups but it's not clear to me why this twig error is showing and i installed the theme twice but no change.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "extension/soconfig/options_stores.twig" is not defined in "extension/soconfig/soconfig.twig" at line 68. in /home1/genniest/ocartdata/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ArrayLoader.php:70 Stack trace: #0 /home1/genniest/ocartdata/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(299): Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader->getCacheKey('extension/socon...') #1 /home1/genniest/ocartdata/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(381): Twig\Environment->getTemplateClass('extension/socon...') #2 /home1/genniest/ocartdata/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(333): Twig\Environment->loadTemplate('extension/socon...', NULL) #3 /home1/genniest/ocartdata/storage/cache/template/30/30f20f91d70c5ca5928f3f2aeda95ebdd7bc3e7320bcf7dbff0ce113184be63b.php(213): Twig\Template->loadTemplate('extension/socon...', 'extension/socon...', 68) #4 /home1/genniest/ocartdata/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_2eb9927c3e6095c1a9edf223e3b350277bc7036e77fce5ce00ab99f91471b0c5->doD in /home1/genniest/ocartdata/storage/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ArrayLoader.php on line 70

[image]

And the file **options_stores.twig** really exists

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well finally i found the solution i wanted to share for everyone to know .. the problem was because of using `{% include %}` inside theme files and it looks like there is a new update in twig library that was not handled by opencart.

The problem is explained [here](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=219092)

And the solution found [here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/pull/7153#issuecomment-50014315)

I hope this can help anyone face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bugfix for opencart Version 3.0.3.8 with latest maintenance patches from

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/tree/3.0.x.x_Maintenance

Date 04/19/2023

---

Navigate to

> /system/library/template/twig.php

Replace :

```
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader(array($filename . '.twig' => $code));
```

With

```
    $loader1 = new \Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader(array($filename . '.twig' => $code));
    $loader2 = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(array(DIR_TEMPLATE)); // to find further includes
    $loader = new \Twig\Loader\ChainLoader(array($loader1, $loader2));
```